# Oracle 11g java.sql.BatchUpdateException: No more data to read from socket on merge query

Tags: java, oracle11g

i have Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

and using latest JAVA ojdbc driver in windows (tested with ver 7 and 8 ) 
when i execute this query which contain CLOB column:
im getting :

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: No more data to read from socket
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10028)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9835)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
```

The sql query looks like this :

```
String s= "...3000 char long string";
    String query = "merge into MY_TABLE t using (select 'ID' as ID,'DATA' as DATA  from dual) s on (t.id=s.id) " +
                    " when matched then " +
                    " update set ID='x',DATA= ? " +
                    " when not matched then " +
                    " INSERT  (ID,DATA) VALUES ('y',s)";

  PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  p.setString(1,s);
  p.addBatch();
  p.executeBatch();
```

What can be the problem ?
Also i did try all suggestion that is offered when i googled the Exception .